# Why is Auth._currentUser not recommended in angular_devise?

Tags: angularjs, devise

Per angular_devise docs, https://github.com/cloudspace/angular_devise, using `Auth._currentUser` is frowned upon.

> **Auth._currentUser**
>
> Auth._currentUser will be either null or the currentUser's object
>   representation. It is not recommended to directly access
>   Auth._currentUser, but instead use Auth.currentUser().

Why is this a bad idea?

I'm currently using it in an application because it allows me to be more concise and add functionality with fewer lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underscored properties and methods are considered private, this means that this part of API can be changed without notice and their usage can lead to unforeseen circumstances.

Since getting current user is asynchronous operation, promise-based `Auth.currentUser()` should be used instead.

The last but not the least concern is that calls to `Auth.currentUser` can be spied in specs, this improves testability.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean `changed without notice`; changed by someone else?

Comment: @pandaman By API creators (angular-devise). It can be removed or renamed or changed in any way they feel it necessary. Don't use underscored stuff in production code, unless you unit-test it thoroughly.